# Do you have to pay a fee for Web Content Accessibility (WCA) before Amazon accepts your ebook?

Tags: self-publishing, ebook, amazon

Below is the letter Sketprofs sent me.
Any information about this would be greatly appreciated.

---

Hello Brett,

This is to inform you that we will have to take your E-book off from Amazon due to non-accessible content. Therefore.  we will have to make it complaint with Web Content Accessibility to make your content more accessible to people with disabilities. Web Content Accessibility (WCA) to make web content more accessible to people with disabilities. WCA covers websites, digital content, and application. It is developed by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI). WCA is an international standard.

There are three levels of conformance:

- Level A is the minimum level.
- Level AA includes all Level A and AA requirements
- Level AAA includes all Level A, AA, and AAA requirements.

WCA is primarily intended for:

- Web content developers (page authors, website designers, etc.)
- Web authoring tool developers
- Web accessibility evaluation tool developers
- Others who want or need a standard for web accessibility, including for mobile accessibility

The Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) prohibits discrimination against people with disabilities:

People with disabilities like sight loss, dyslexia or a physically limiting disability can read using eBook technologies. I will highlight some of the potential challenges and walk you through the steps we need to take to make your publication more accessible to this global audience of people with disabilities.

For individuals with low vision, control over the way text is presented is essential. Many people with a visual impairment may simply need to enlarge the size of the text before they can read it and in some cases, this can mean increasing the scale so only one or two words fit on the screen at a time.

People with certain eye conditions also benefit from increasing the contrast of the text from the background, with yellow and black being a common color combination used interchangeably for text and background colors. It is not uncommon for the reading requirements of people with low vision to change throughout the day, typically needing to increase the text size later in the day as their eyes get tired.

Level AA is required to meet the requirement.

Cost: $1,299 but for you, as you are an existing client, the cost is $799 and that’s only for you.

THANK YOU,
SHAWN WILSON

Comment: What is "Sketprofs"?

Comment: Not just a scam, but most likely phishing as well.

Answer (score 6):

Business Correspondence with misspellings and punctuation errors are a red flag for a scam.

Amazon recommends your e-book be accessible, but does not require it, according to their [guidelines](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GGRXLC5USU4H67YM):

> To ensure a high-quality experience for all readers, Amazon recommends testing the accessibility of your book. Tools for checking content accessibility will vary based on your book format.
>
> - Word: Use the built-in [Accessibility Checker within Microsoft Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/improve-accessibility-with-the-accessibility-checker-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
> - PDF: Use the built-in [Accessibility Checker within Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/acrobat/using-acrobat-pro-accessibility-checker.html)
> - EPUB: Use the [ACE Accessibility Checker from the DAISY Consortium](https://inclusivepublishing.org/toolbox/accessibility-checker/getting-started/)
> - HTML: Convert your HTML file to Word and review content accessibility with the Microsoft Accessibility Checker.
>
> Amazon recommends resolving all accessibility errors before uploading your manuscript to Kindle.

The link provides their recommendations on determining if you e-book has any problems with accessibility.

Comment: Yep.. this is a scam and the OP should file it straight in the bin.

Comment: Additional hint: "we will have to take your E-book off Amazon" -- if that were actually happening, it would already be gone, Amazon would have done it, and you'd have the Devil's own time finding out why they pulled your book -- or *Amazon* would have emailed you directly telling you it's already been pulled.